# How to create manual menuentry for different disk in rEFInd?

Tags: boot-loader, refind

So, my setup is the following:

```
# lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,type,fstype

sda                                           698,7G disk 
└─sda3                             Manjaro     48,9G part ext4
sdb                                           119,2G disk 
├─sdb1 /boot                       SYSTEM       100M part vfat
├─sdb3                             OS          65,9G part ntfs
├─sdb5 /                                       35,4G part ext4
```

(Some partitions hidden as they are not relevant.)

As you can see, `/dev/sda3` is on a different drive of the EFI partition `SYSTEM`.
I can easily create a menuentry for `/dev/sdb5`. But not for `/dev/sda3`.
Here is my (unsuccessfull) attempt:

```
menuentry "Manjaro" {
   icon         /efi/refind/icons/os_manjaro.png
   volume       "Manjaro"
   loader       /vmlinuz-4.14-x86_64
   initrd       /initramfs-4.14-x86_64.img
   options      "root=uuid=0151dca4-34a5-4e50-b1e9-26ff1fbbe1d7 rw quiet                     pcie_aspm=force i915.u915_enable_rc6=1"
   submenuentry "boot using fallback initramfs" {
            initrd /initramfs-4.14-x86_64-fallback.img
   }
   submenuentry "boot to terminal" {
            add_options "systemd.unit=multi-user.target"
   }
   disabled
}
```

I kind of understand why this doesn't work, rEFInd is searching for `vmlinuz-4.14-x86_64` in `SYSTEM` EFI partition, but it's not there (obviously).
How can I make it search in `Manjaro` partition? I'd rather not have to copy the images to `SYSTEM` partition :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rEFInd relies on the UEFI firmware for filesystem access, and VFAT is the only guaranteed-supported filesystem type by the UEFI standard. I've seen some Asus system boards claim NTFS support in the firmware, and Apple laptops' UEFI will support Apple HFS+ filesystem.

You'll need to have rEFInd first load a driver that enables it to read ext4 filesystems. Then it should work, assuming that your `sda` disk is already detected by the UEFI firmware. If your `sda` is, for example, connected through an add-on card that is not recognized by the firmware and the manufacturer of the add-on card does not provide a UEFI driver for it (either embedded in a card firmware or as a loadable .EFI file), then you may be out of luck.

rEFInd is designed to use EFI drivers if necessary, and its developer maintains a collection of EFI drivers for various filesystem types:
http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/drivers.html

Comment: Well, rEFInd does recognize the Manjaro grub .EFI file. But I'd like to not do it with grub if possible. Does grub work in a different way from rEFInd?

Comment: rEFInd recognizes the grub.EFI file because it's located in the ESP, which is a VFAT filesystem (your SYSTEM partition). GRUB has some filesystem drivers built in to its code, so it can read ext4 filesystems even if the firmware cannot. For using .EFI drivers with rEFInd (and for downloading an EFI driver for ext4) see here: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/drivers.html